# Android Extra Project Eclipse - NoClassDefFoundError- Not on every computer

Tags: java, android, eclipse, project

We are working on an Android project and we have a project called PubData which contains some shared classes. For most of us, there is no problem. However, for one of us, we get NoClassDefFoundError every time we run.

Our .classpath file (which is in Git) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" exported="true" kind="src" path="/PubData"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Our build paths are the same, what could this be?

Comment: have you tried cleaning your project and build again?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the PubData project is indeed present in that user's workspace, that the project is not in the "closed" state, and that there are no compile problems in it.

Comment: None of these are the issue unfortunately